# Error while pull/fetch changes from branch in WebStorm

Tags: git, github, webstorm, git-pull, git-fetch

Cannot fetch/pull changes from remote branch.

I executed git command in WebStorm terminal: `git pull origin dev`

Got this issue:

```
fatal: bad object refs/heads/dev 2
error: github.com:MyProgect/settings.git did not send all necessary objects
```

I could not see any commit from all branches, probably it's a GitHub issue in WebStorm:

[image]

Comment: are you going through a proxy?